# Which is the default web server running on NodeJS based Azure Web App(Linux)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Trying to deploy and access reactjs mono repo application on Azure WA.
 Which is the default web server running on NodeJS based Azure Web App(Linux)?
How fo I run node.js apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the App Service on Linux docker images for NodeJS uses PM2 as the underlying web server. Most of the images that are available for various frameworks are available here: https://hub.docker.com/r/appsvc/

You can view the dockerfile for the NodeJS image version 8.1.2 here: https://hub.docker.com/r/appsvc/node

Here is a snippet of the dockerfile for your reference:

```
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/startup \
     && mkdir /opt/pm2 \
     && chmod 777 /opt/pm2 \
     && ln -s /opt/pm2/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 /usr/local/bin/pm2

USER node

RUN cd /opt/pm2 \
  && npm install pm2 \
  && cd /opt/startup \
  && npm install

USER root

# End workaround

EXPOSE 2222 8080

ENV PM2HOME /pm2home

ENV PORT 8080
ENV WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID localRoleInstance
ENV WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID localInstance
ENV PATH ${PATH}:/home/site/wwwroot

WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
```